# How to order the null values?

Tags: ms-access

Using Access 2003

In my table column, some of the fields are null, some of the fields are number, and some of the fields are string

Table.

```
ID, Value

001 
002 N/A
003 01
004  
005 N/A
006 02
```

So on...

I want to order the table by number, string then null values,

Query,

Select ID, Value from table order by value

Expected Output

```
    ID, Values

    003 01
    006 02
    002 N/A
    005 N/A
    001
    004
```

Need Query Help

Comment: What data type is Value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  SELECT * FROM  
 (SELECT *, IIF(Val(Value) > 0, 2, IIF(ISNULL(Value), 3, 1)) AS MyOrder FROM MyTable)  
Order by MyOrder
```

EDIT: I think this one is clear. Modified as per Robert's query ;)

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable
ORDER BY IIF(Val(Value) > 0, 2, IIF(ISNULL(Value), 3, 1))
```

Answer (score 10):

Create a new query, and insert the following SQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1
ORDER BY IsNull([Text2]) DESC , Table1.Text2;
```

Change the names as appropriate.

Comment: +1 -- this is better than using an IIF statement, which is just as inefficient and slow as you might guess it to be.